# How to add interval to a draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I created a bar which you can select different intervals. I am attempting to make it draggable, which I successfully implemented. The issue I have is that I can drag the green grab bar (where is says "budget"). I am wanting to be able to drag the grab bar and then for it to drop where the range dots are (the intervals) and keep the grab bar within the outer element `#sliderBar`.

Is there anyway I can change what I have to make this possible?

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hL4v1ajt/)

```js
 $(function() {
   $("#sliderInterval").draggable();
 });
 $(function() {

   var iSelected = 0;
   var ranges = [{
     lower: 500,
     upper: 1000
   }, {
     lower: 1100,
     upper: 2000
   }, {
     lower: 2100,
     upper: 5000
   }, {
     lower: 5100,
     upper: 10000
   }, {
     lower: 11000,
     upper: 20000
   }, {
     lower: 21000,
     upper: 50000
   }, ];
   var wslider = $("#sliderBar").width() / (ranges.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
     var range = $('<div class="rangedot"><div class="intervalCircle"></div></div>');
     var left = (100 / (ranges.length) * i);
     rangeleft = "calc(" + left + "% - 2px)";
     range.css({
       left: rangeleft,
       width: wslider
     });
     range.on("click", function(idx) {
       return function() {
         iSelected = idx;
         var sliderleft = wslider * idx;
         $("#sliderInterval").animate({
           left: sliderleft
         });
         $("#budgetAmount").text("$" + ranges[idx].lower.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + " - " + "$" + ranges[idx].upper.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
       };
     }(i));
     $("#sliderBar").append(range);
     $("#sliderInterval").css("width", wslider + "px");
   }
   $("#budgetAmount").show().text("$500 - $1,000");

 });
```

```css
#project-slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 40px 0% 30px 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

#project-slider-title {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#project-slider-description {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

#sliderBar {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: #454343;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intervalCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.intervalCircle:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #0085A1;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rangedot {
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  top: -8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sliderInterval {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #00a16d;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#sliderIntervalBudget {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#budgetAmount {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #00a16d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="project-slider-container">
  <div id="project-slider-title">PREFERRED BUDGET</div>
  <div id="sliderBar">
    <div id="sliderInterval"><span id="sliderIntervalBudget">BUDGET</span></div>
  </div>
  <div id="budgetAmount"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't be done with the jQuery UI Slider?

Comment: @Twisty Maybe with the snap to increments, but I want the increments to be defined. Do you know if that can be done?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in Slider. Review: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

Comment: @Twisty I see the steps, but how would I identify ranges, like I did in my code.

Comment: Using the `min`, `max`, and `range` options for Slider. Let me see if I can adjust your fiddle to show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using Slider.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1846p0nx/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="project-slider-container">
  <div id="project-slider-title">PREFERRED BUDGET</div>
  <div id="project-slider-description">A transparent budget will help set expectations. A higher budget allows for a more complex website project.</div>
  <div class="slide-wrap">
    <div id="slider">
      <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle">BUDGET</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="budgetAmount"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-wrap {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 60px;
  background: #454343;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#slider {
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 60px;
}

#custom-handle {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #00a16d;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
   var ranges = [{
     lower: 500,
     upper: 1000
   }, {
     lower: 1100,
     upper: 2000
   }, {
     lower: 2100,
     upper: 5000
   }, {
     lower: 5100,
     upper: 10000
   }, {
     lower: 11000,
     upper: 20000
   }, {
     lower: 21000,
     upper: 50000
   }, ];
   var handle = $("#custom-handle");
   var amount = $("#budgetAmount");
   $("#slider").slider({
     min: 0,
     max: 5,
     step: 1,
     create: function() {
       var i = $(this).slider("value");
       amount.text("$" + ranges[i].lower + " - $" + ranges[i].upper);
       $.each(ranges, function(key, item) {
         var range = $("<div>", {
           class: "rangedot"
         }).data("key", key);
         var dot = $("<div>", {
           class: "intervalCircle"
         }).appendTo(range);
         var l = Math.round(100 / (ranges.length - 1) * key);
         var w = $("#slider").width() / (ranges.length);
         range.css({
           left: "calc(" + l + "% - " + (w / 2) + "px)",
           width: w + "px"
         }).click(function() {
           $("#slider").slider("value", $(this).data("key"));
         }).appendTo("#slider");
       });
     },
     slide: function(event, ui) {
       var i = ui.value;
       amount.text("$" + ranges[i].lower + " - $" + ranges[i].upper);
     }
   });
});
```

**Update**

If you want to do this with draggable specifically, I would suggest this.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1846p0nx/4/

```
$(function() {
   var iSelected = 0;
   var ranges = [{
     lower: 500,
     upper: 1000
   }, {
     lower: 1100,
     upper: 2000
   }, {
     lower: 2100,
     upper: 5000
   }, {
     lower: 5100,
     upper: 10000
   }, {
     lower: 11000,
     upper: 20000
   }, {
     lower: 21000,
     upper: 50000
   }];
   var wslider = $("#sliderBar").width() / (ranges.length);
   $("#sliderInterval").draggable({
     axis: "x",
     grid: [wslider, 0],
     containment: "#sliderBar",
   });
   for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
     var range = $('<div class="rangedot"><div class="intervalCircle"></div></div>');
     var left = (100 / (ranges.length) * i);
     rangeleft = "calc(" + left + "% - 2px)";
     range.css({
       left: rangeleft,
       width: wslider
     });
     range.on("click", function(idx) {
       return function() {
         iSelected = idx;
         var sliderleft = wslider * idx;
         $("#sliderInterval").animate({
           left: sliderleft
         });
         $("#budgetAmount").text("$" + ranges[idx].lower.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + " - " + "$" + ranges[idx].upper.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
       };
     }(i));
     $("#sliderBar").append(range);
     $("#sliderInterval").css("width", wslider + "px");
   }
   $("#budgetAmount").show().text("$500 - $1,000");
});
```

You can then use `stop` or create a droppable to go along with it to see where it was dropped. I still suggest the slider.

Comment: I see the HTML but I do not see jQuery that initializes the slider.

Comment: IT does not appear that `#slider` was initialized at all by jQuery. There appears to be a lot of other code that could be interfering.

Comment: I think the issue was my cloudflare service wasn't allowing the changes to show, so I put it into development mode. Then I had a closing } error, which I fixed and now it works. What changes did you make in the link you just shared?

Comment: Changed `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` to `$(function(){`. Removed function wrapping from `$('#white-green-section').animate()`, it's not needed. Removed `$(function() {` before `//For human test`, it's not needed at this point in the code. Tidy'd up the format.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need part of my original code, the part between my comments? https://jsfiddle.net/1846p0nx/7/

Comment: Sorry to keep commenting, but I don't understand why my ranges are not being detected in my ajax... `var range_upper = ranges[iSelected].upper;
      var range_lower = ranges[iSelected].lower;`

Comment: @Paul what is the value of `iSelected`?

Comment: It is set to 0 initially, here is that targeted code.  thenhttps://jsfiddle.net/gqnk2pcg/

Comment: @Paul if it's only updated in `click` event, by: `iSelected = idx;`, this will have issues. `idx` is an event object in this case. You'd want to do something like `iSelected = $(idx.target).index();`

Comment: I don't understand if it is the range issue or what, but since adding this the page doesn't even submit the form now. The page just reloads and the ajax doesn't send me to php file.

Comment: @Paul I have no idea at this point. Not sure what code is being used. Check your console for errors.

Comment: I appreciate the help!